# What's the purpose of the "bin" group?

Tags: users

Where is it usually used? Where can I read about it, and other often used groups?

Comment: You can read about it at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485505/ .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `base-passwd` package guarantees the presence of certain users and certain groups in a system. The documentation is in `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.txt.gz` (or `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.html`) (source available online in [Debian Salsa](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/base-passwd/blob/master/doc/users-and-groups.sgml)):

```
bin

    HELP: No files on my system are owned by user or group bin. What good are
    they? Historically they were probably the owners of binaries in /bin? It is
    not mentioned in the FHS, Debian Policy, or the changelogs of base-passwd
    or base-files.

    LSB 1.3 lists bin as legacy, and says: "The 'bin' UID/GID is included for
    compatibility with legacy applications. New applications should no longer
    use the 'bin' UID/GID."
```

So, it's part of the [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) specification, and since Debian used to aim for LSB compliance, Ubuntu has a `bin` user and group.

Answer (score 7):

`/usr` was the original path for user homes in historic Unix, so there was a `bin` user in charge of `/usr/bin` - compare how the root user is implemented in these (and also in some more modern ones - Solaris, etc.) systems, it has `/`, not `/root`, as home directory.